# Expanding a wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, hilbert-space, fourier-transform

I have a wave function that I have already normalised:

$$
\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{30}{a^{5}}}x(a-x)
$$

but now I have been asked to expand it to get:

$$
\psi(x) = \sqrt{\frac{960}{\pi^{6}}}\sum_{k} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^{3}}u_{2k+1}(x)
$$

I can see that it probably has something to do with the Fourier series and tried to mess around with it and ended up getting:

$$
\psi(x) = 4\sqrt{\frac{30}{\pi^{3}}}\sum \frac{1}{(n)^{3}\sqrt{a^5}}\sin(kx)
$$

but honestly do not know where to go with this question or if I am doing the right thing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be on the right lines. Show your workings in detail and maybe someone will point out where you've gone wrong.

Comment: The waveform is odd, the solution to the fourier series was: $\psi (x) = \int_{0}^{a}x(a-x)sin(\frac{n\pi x}{a})dx = \left\{ 
\begin{matrix}
\frac{4a^{3}}{n^{3}\pi^{3}}\\ 
0
\end{matrix}\right.$ I think u(x) may be an eigenstate as it is in the context of an electron in a 1-d box?